# Handle different Firebase Auth Providers

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I was wondering what should be best practices using various Firebase Auth providers. 
I have a Flutter project, that use Firebase Auth Google and mail providers to sign up the user.

The problems is, that some users have more permissions if they have verified their phone number. Because of this I had to implement the Phone Auth provider too, but now when user verify their number it automatically signs in with the new ID because there's no way to separate the phone verification from the sign in process.

At first I thought that deleting the new user should give me an easy solution of this, but when you delete the user it signs it off too so It doesn't work the way I need.

I think it should be easy to switch to the 'original' user when I create the new one, but then I will still have one user with 2 IDs and it seems a little bit chaotic this way.

So, does anyone faced the same problem and what was their solution?
If not, would you help me to find the best way to handle this situation?

Edit: Just in case someone have the idea to give the user the option to sign up using the phone provider when they signs up, it's not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single user signing in with multiple providers, it's expected that you tell Firebase Authentication to link the accounts so they all share the same identity.  The [documentation for web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) discusses this at length.  I'm sure the APIs and procedure are similar for flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the flutter code, just in case someone needs it:

```
void _linkWithCredential() async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: _verificationId,
      smsCode: _smsController.text,
    );
     (await _auth.currentUser()).linkWithCredential(credential);
  }
```